# Piezo electric buzzer as a crystal earpiece?

Tags: radio, crystal, piezo-buzzer

Making a foxhole radio, saw on https://rimstar.org/equip/crystal_earphone_earpiece_for_crystal_radio.htm

can you actually use a buzzer as a crystal earpiece?

Comment: Test it and find out.

Answer (score 1):

The piezo discs are alike.

The problem is in the naming that people use of the component.

Many people say a piezo buzzer even if they just mean a piezo disc.

The buzzer circuit just is a circuit that takes power supply in and outputs a tone to a piezo disc. When these are combined into a single component, that is a piezo buzzer.

So basically, you can't use a device with built-in buzzer circuit as a piezo speaker, but you can use a device which only contains the piezo element in a plastic housing as a piezo speaker, because that literally is a piezo speaker.